# How i can get the location data {latitude,longitude,Address} of whatsapp using the Twilio API?

Tags: salesforce, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, whatsapi

I am not receiving location data `{latitude,longitude,Address}` from response whatsapp using the Twilio API. I have also tried using `postman` to get location data but did not get `{latitude,longitude,Address}`.

```
{
  "body": "",
  "index": 11,
  "author": "system",
  "date_updated": "2023-04-26T07:55:38Z",
  "media": null,
  "participant_sid": null,
  "conversation_sid": "CH9cc81eda2bfe4533b9bac03ab0a4f34e",
  "account_sid": "AC2b01ca3231c130f24aacd13a4f80e5e7",
  "delivery": null,
  "url": "https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Conversations/CH9cc81eda2bfe4533b9bac03ab0a4f34e/Messages/IMa82bee8d8efc42f086578111cf03d51a",
  "date_created": "2023-04-26T07:55:38Z",
  "content_sid": null,
  "sid": "IMa82bee8d8efc42f086578111cf03d51a",
  "attributes": "{}",
  "links": {
      "delivery_receipts": "https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Conversations/CH9cc81eda2bfe4533b9bac03ab0a4f34e/Messages/IMa82bee8d8efc42f086578111cf03d51a/Receipts"
  }
}
```

I am expecting

```
 "location": {
            "latitude": 37.62159755922449,
            "longitude": -122.37888566473057,
            "label": "Time to Board @ SFO"
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you used to receive the data aka the webhook?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is available through the Twilio WhatsApp API. Looking at the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api/message-resource#message-properties), there is no location property of a message resource. Is there somewhere in the documentation that you were seeing this property?

Comment: is correct, while you can send and receive location data via WhatsApp, it's not available in the API after the messages have been sent/received. You can however capture [the location data in the webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/message-features#receive-inbound-location-messages) and store it yourself for future reference.